# Calculate probability rolling a die $10$ times

Tags: probability

I you roll a die $10$ times:

What is the probability of getting at least a  one and at least a two?

I tried to use the complement rule and find the probabilities of not getting a one and not getting a two. As I have four numbers left the probability is 
$= 1  - \frac{4^{10}}{6^{10}} = 0.9826$ . But the right answers is $0.6943$

Thank you.

Comment: You've worked out the probability of getting a one *or* a two, not the probability of getting a one *and* a two.

Comment: I didn't copy it well. It is at least a one and at least a two. (instead of some one and some two)Sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\scriptsize\rm P(1.2)=P((1'+2')')=1-P(1'+2')=1-[P(1')+P(2')-P(1'.2')]=1-\left[\frac{5^{10}}{6^{10}}+\frac{5^{10}}{6^{10}}-\frac{4^{10}}{6^{10}}\right]=\frac{6^{10}-2\times5^{10}+4^{10}}{6^{10}}\\\approx \color{red}{0.6943}\color{grey}{30364...}$$

Comment: Thank you for your answers.
$P(1.2)= P((1´+2´)´)$ If I use Morgan's Law  $(1'+2')' = 1''.2'' = 1.2.$ But, I don't understand it well. For instance, if the question is to find the probability of getting at least one one, then, I see clearly that it is $P(1)= 1 - P(1')$. 
So if the question is: What it is probability of getting at least one one and at least one two. Then my first thought it is $P(1.2) = P(1'.2')'$,which is wrong by Morgan's Law)And if the question was, What is the probability of getting at least one one or at least one two I'd say $P(1+2)=((1'+2'))'$

Comment: I can't understand what you want to ask. Should I explain De Morgan's Law?

Comment: Without using Morgan's Law, how can you see that $P(1.2)= P((1´+2´)´)$?

Comment: @dudha try using venn diagrams.

Answer (score 1):

Consider four possible outcomes of the $10$ rolls:

- You roll no ones and no twos. The probability of this is 
  $p_0 = \frac{4^{10}}{6^{10}}$
  as you correctly derived from the fact that the outcome of each roll
  is three, four, five, or six.
- You roll at least one "one", but you do not roll any twos. Let this have probability $p_1$.
- You roll at least one "two", but you do not roll any ones. Let this have probability $p_2$.
- You roll at least one "one" and also at least one "two". Let this have probability $p_3$.

The last case is the one whose probability you want to measure,
$p_3 = 1 - (p_0 + p_1 + p_2).$

As you can see, $p_1 = p_2$. To calculate $p_1$, you can take the probability
that you do not roll any twos, and subtract the probability that you do not roll any ones or twos. That is, if $A_1$ is the event that at least one "one" is rolled,
and $A_1$ is the event that at least one "two" is rolled, then

$$P(A_2^\complement)
 = P(A_1 \cap A_2^\complement) + P(A_1^\complement \cap A_2^\complement)$$
and therefore
$$p_1 = P(A_1 \cap A_2^\complement) 
= P(A_2^\complement) - P(A_1^\complement \cap A_2^\complement).$$

If you write out $p_0 + p_1 + p_2$ in this manner, you will find that the sum
simplifies to
$$p_0 + p_1 + p_2 =
 P(A_2^\complement) + P(A_2^\complement) - P(A_1^\complement \cap A_2^\complement),$$
which is an application of the Inclusion-Exclusion principle to this problem.

Comment: Thank you. I tried to do the second and third case, which have the same probability. In order to get at least one one $P(1) = 1 - \frac{5^{10}}{6^{10}}$ $= 0.8384$ and to get no twos is $\frac{5^{10}}{6^{10}}= 0.1615 $. And here I get stuck because I don't know when I can do $P(1.2')= 0.8384 ·0.1615= 0.1354 $ and when not.

Comment: I have edited the answer to try to explain the second and third cases.